# How did they build this user interface?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm an experienced programmer but have started with Objective-C a few months ago. I have a couple apps on the go and so far so good.
I am comfortable with view controllers, table views, and your basic UI stuff that you see in every book/tutorial, but I've recently downloaded the Holographium app and the UI blew my mind. Of course, I want to know how to do that now!

What blew me away was not only the look (which can easily be achieved by a competent designer) but how every little button you touch animates and the UI sort of "transitions" to another state. I know how to apply an image here and there to a table view but this is much much more than that.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how this could have been achieved? (no need for code, just general concepts).

Since it's a paid app, I'm posting screenshots here:
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=holographium+ui&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=344l4443l0l4953l16l13l0l0l0l0l473l5187l3-7.6l13l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1440&bih=707&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=HQQLT_qjGMvogQfNroigAg

Thanks!

EDIT: I posted this question in MacRumors and the very author of the app in question posted the answer! http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=14329964

Comment: i think you should add a special GUI libraries to make them available in your project.
here is some short info, it's well explained: [link](http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=node/14)

Comment: @aspirinemaga thanks for the link, but it explains how to build an extremely basic UI which has none of the features of the one in the app I posted.

Comment: I don't think so they are using any 3rd party GUI libraries. Animation is very cool and you can do it in objective C not very easily but it will take time. You can achieve same UI using core graphics very easily.

Comment: @Amit Vyawahare, thanks for the info. What kind of navigation controller do you thing they used?

Comment: Have you every worked on CGAffineTransformMakeScale for viewcontroller. This is perfect example for one view with three diffract subview which get animated when you trigger them with CGAffineTransformMakeScale view transform. I can't add answer to popst code here.

Comment: @Amit Vyawahare thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know! I'll look into that class (I've never even heard of it).